# wordpress contact form messages not sending although it saying they were sent successfully with this php code

Tags: php, wp-admin, forms, localhost

this is a contact form code which works and when I submit the message, it says thanks it was sent successfully, but unfortunately I have not got any messages. I use it on wordpress on local host.

what should I change in order to get the messages?? any help please

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError = 'Please enter your name.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }


    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Please enter your email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }


    if(trim($_POST['subject']) === '') {
        $subjectError = 'Please enter a subject.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }


    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'Please enter a message.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = get_option('tz_email');
        if (!isset($emailTo) || ($emailTo == '') ){
            $emailTo = get_option('admin_email');
        }
        $subject = '[PHP Snippets] From '.$name;
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }

} ?>




        <hr class="no-margin" />

        <div class="blog-container section-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="box-layer custom-padding">





    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">



<div class="align-center">

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { ?>
                            <div class="thanks">
                                <p>Thanks, your email was sent successfully.</p>
                            </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php if(isset($hasError) || isset($captchaError)) { ?>
                                <p class="error">Sorry, an error occured.<p>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" class="general-form">
                            <div class="contactform">
                            <p>

                                <input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" id="contactName" placeholder="Your Name.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>" class="required requiredField" />
                                <?php if($nameError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$nameError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </p>



                            <p>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email']))  echo $_POST['email'];?>" class="required requiredField email" />
                                <?php if($emailError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$emailError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </p>


                                <p>
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Subject.." value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject']))  echo $_POST['subject'];?>" class="required requiredField subject" />
                                <?php if($subjectError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$subjectError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </p>



                            <p>
                                <textarea name="comments" id="commentsText" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message" rows="4" cols="100" class="required requiredField"><?php if(isset($_POST['comments'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['comments']); } else { echo $_POST['comments']; } } ?></textarea>
                                <?php if($commentError != '') { ?>
                                    <span class="error"><?=$commentError;?></span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary no-border" value="Send Message"></input>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                    </form>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>



                    </div>
                </div></div>





                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mail() function (used by wp_mail() function, assuming there is no other mail plugin added to your site) sends the mail stuff to your domain's mail server. It only knows if the message was recieved by the mail server. It does not know if the message was actually sent out by your mail server.

One of the things that can cause problems is that the 'from' email sent via the mail() function must be a email address in your domain. It does not have to exist, just has to be from your domain.

For example, if your domain is www.example.com , then the 'from' email needs to be 'anything@example.com'. It cannot be 'anything@anotherdomain.com'. That will be blocked by your mail server.

So it is important the the sender of your message be in your domain. If not, your email server - or a recipient's mail server - will sense the message as being probably spam, and will refuse/block/not send your message.

You can set the 'reply-to' header value to anything, even an email not in your domain, but the sender MUST be an email address that matches your domain.

Note that the wp_mail() function sends mail from the 'default Wordpress email' account. You must make sure that this is set up properly. This setting is in Settings, General, Administration Account. That value must be set to something@yourdomain.com , replacing your domain name.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply, so what if I am using the local host?

Comment: If your site is running on localhost, then you need to configure your local email server to accept email from whatever value you have in the Administration Email account in Settings, General. Or you can install a WP SMTP plugin to change how email works. One hint on how to configure your localhost email server is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419712/1466973 , there are other sources of information you can find via the googles/bings/ducks.